# Cryptography methods that allow for multiple keys to be used?

Tags: encryption, keys

I'm currently working on a webapp in which I'd like all nearly all user data to be encrypted, but accessible by multiple users (ie a doc encrypted should be decrypt-able by parties A, B, C, all independently). Is there any way to achieve this?

One issue I realized is that it would be nearly impossible based on my knowledge to append users to have access to docs (ie allow party D to now access that prior document), as I'd need to re-encrypt the plaintext, but as I don't have access to that, I couldn't, correct?

Comment: Use key derivation / key encapsulation using multiple key pairs to derive the same data key, used to encrypt the messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to do. This is called *key wrapping*. You generate a random "master" symmetric key (called the DEK, or Data Encryption Key) and use it to encrypt the data. You then derive a key called a KEK (Key Encryption Key) from a user's passphrase or other key material. The KEK is used to encrypt the DEK. The encrypted DEK, or eDEK, is stored alongside the encrypted data.

To add a new user, you use a valid KEK to decrypt the DEK, then have the new user supply a new KEK which is used to encrypt the DEK again. The new eDEK can then be appended to the data.

The data you store will end up looking like this, assuming you have it encrypted for three users:

```
eDEK_1 || eDEK_2 || eDEK_3 || encrypted_data
```

See [RFC 3394](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3394) for an example of how this can be done.

Comment: The trick is basically that instead of encrypting 100 MB with five different keys you encrypt a single, unchanging, _tiny_ key with 5 different keys.

Comment: When a user is changing their password or gets a new password created via password-lost-feature, we have to re-create then all their KEK for all encrypted Documents to keep the access to them, right?

Comment: @delete The encrypted DEK must be decrypted with a previous password, then re-encrypted with a new KEK and stored.